# How to convert UIImage to JPEG without loosing exif data?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

I'm currently working on iOS applications and I'm using multipart image upload to uploading images to the server. Following is my image uploading method.

```
func uploadImageData(imageType:Int, uploadId:String, fileName:String, imageFile:UIImage, completion:@escaping (APIResponseStatus, ImageUploadResponse?) -> Void) {

        let image = imageFile
        let imgData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)!

        let params = [APIRequestKeys.imageType:imageType, APIRequestKeys.uploadId:uploadId, APIRequestKeys.fileName:fileName] as [String : Any]
        //withName is the post request key for the image file
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: APIRequestKeys.imageFile, fileName: "\(fileName).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                for (key, value) in params {
                    multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
        }, to: Constants.baseUrl + APIRequestMetod.uploadImageData, headers:self.getImageUploadHeaders())
            { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    APIClient.currentRequest = upload
                    upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    })
                    upload.responseObject {
                        (response:DataResponse<ImageUploadResponse>) in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .success(_):
                            completion(APIClient.APIResponseStatus(rawValue: (response.response?.statusCode)!)!, response.value!)
                        case .failure(let encodingError):
                            if let err = encodingError as? URLError, err.code == .notConnectedToInternet {
                                completion(APIClient.APIResponseStatus.NoNetwork, nil)
                            } else {
                                completion(APIClient.APIResponseStatus.Other, nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                case .failure( _):
                    completion(APIClient.APIResponseStatus.Other, nil)
                }
            }
        }
```

But for this implementation server is always sending exif data error. Following is the error that I'm getting.

```
exif_read_data(A029C715-99E4-44BE-8691-AA4009C1F5BD_FOTOPREGUNTA.ico): Illegal IFD size in
upload_image_xhr.php on line
```

The important thing is this service is working without errors in POSTMAN and android application as well. This error is only getting for my iOS implementation. My backend developer telling me that there is and exif data error in data that I'm sending and please verify the data from my side.
Anyone have an idea about this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will make block function for Upload image to Server Using Multipart

```
//Here strUrl = YOUR WEBSERVICE URL
//postParam = post Request parameter i.e. 
//let postParam : [String : Any] = [first_name : "name"]
//imageArray = image upload array i.e.
//var imageArray : [[String:Data]] = [["image_name" : YOUR IMAGE DATA]]

func postImageRequestWithURL(withUrl strURL: String,withParam postParam: Dictionary<String, Any>,withImages imageArray:[[String:Data]], completion:@escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool, _ response:NSDictionary) -> Void)
{
    let requetURL = strURL

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in

        for (imageDic) in imageArray
        {
            for (key,valus) in imageDic
            {
                MultipartFormData.append(valus, withName:key,fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            }
        }

        for (key, value) in postParam
        {
            MultipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)

          // MultipartFormData.append(value, withName: key)
        }

    }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: requetURL, method: .post, headers: ["Accept": "application/json"]) { (result) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in

                let desiredString = NSString(data: response.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

                print("Response ====================")

                print(desiredString!)

                if let json = response.result.value as? NSDictionary
                {
                    if response.response?.statusCode == 200
                        || response.response?.statusCode == 201
                        || response.response?.statusCode == 202
                    {
                        completion(true,json);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        completion(false,json);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    completion(false,[:]);
                }
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)

            completion(false,[:]);
        }

    }
}
```

I Hope this will help...